# Regex to replace space with new line in vuejs

Tags: javascript

I have a string `James Jack Wilson` and multiple other strings like this. I want to replace the space between these words to a new line. Something like

```
James
Jack
Wilson
```

How can I do this in vuejs?

Comment: `"James Jack Wilson".replace(/\s+/g, "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

```js
"James Jack Wilson".replace(/[\s]+/g, '\n');
```

Comment: Why use a character-class (ie `[\s]`)?

Comment: @Phil Yes, it's not required.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.